# $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ ($a_n\geq0$) with radius of convergence $1$. Prove that $1$ is a singular point of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ ($a_n\geq0$) with radius of convergence $1$. Prove that $1$ is a singular point of $f$.

I proved that $f$ converges on the unit circle. I tried to use uniqueness theorem to prove that if a function $g$ is analytic at $1$, then the zeroes of $f-g$ must be isolated, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: How do you define a "singular point of $f$"? In particular what does it mean when $f$ is not defined in a punctured neighbourhood of the point in question? (Also, your claim that the series converges on the unit circle is incorrect. Take for example $a_n = 1$ for all $n$.)

Comment: Prove that z = 1 is a singular point of f. That is, there is no function g analytic in a neighborhood U of z = 1 such that f = g on U ∩D. I wanted to prove by contradiction, so I supposed that such g exists. That's why I claimed that f converges on the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

This is Exercise 1 from Rudin's RCA, Chapter 16.

We proceed as follows:

Firstly, we know that $f$ has at least one singular point on the unit circle (see Rudin RCA Theorem 16.2).
Now consider $f$ expanded in powers of $z-\frac{1}{2}$:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})}{n!}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \quad \left(z\in D\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
We observe that the radius of convergence of the series above is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Suppose that $f$ was regular at $z=1$, then we would have that the following series converges for some $z$ such that $Im(z) = 0, Re(z)>1$.
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})}{n!}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Since $f(z) = \sum a_nz^n$, then we also have that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    f^{(k)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)a_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})}{n!}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \frac{ m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)a_m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n}}{n!}\right) \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\
        &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n}^{\infty} {m\choose n} a_m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n} \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\
        &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_m \sum_{n=0}^{m} {m\choose n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n} \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\
        &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_m \sum_{n=0}^{m} {m\choose n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n} \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\
        &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_m z^m \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Where the second equality follows by definition of the binomial coefficient.
Clearly, ${m\choose n} a_m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \ge 0$ and the third equality follows as such.
The last equality follows by the Binomial Theorem.

Now we have that the radius of convergence of $f(z) = \sum a_nz^n$ is  greater than 1. But it must be 1, hence a contradiction.
Hence $f$ is not regular at $z=1$, hence $f$ has a singularity at $z=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ admits an analytic extension to $\Omega=B(0;1)\cup B(1;\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. It follows that for some $\varepsilon>0$, the ball $B\big(\tfrac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\big)\subset \Omega$ and so $f\in H(B\big(\tfrac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\big))$. The power series of $f$ around $\frac12$ is
\begin{align*}
    f(z) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{k=n}\binom{k}{n}a_k2^{n-k}\Big)\big(z-\tfrac12\big)^n 
  \end{align*}
which can be obtained from $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_k(z-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^n$ by expanding $(z-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^n$ and using the uniform integrability inside the ball of convergence to change the order of summation.

For some $0<\epsilon<\varepsilon$, $1+\epsilon\in B\big(\tfrac12;\tfrac12+\varepsilon)$. Since $a_n\geq0$, we can change the order of summation (Fubini's theorem for example) to get
\begin{align*}
    f(1+\epsilon) &= \sum^\infty_{n=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{k=n}\binom{k}{n}a_k2^{n-k}\Big)\big(\tfrac12+\epsilon\big)^n\\
    &= \sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k\Big(\sum^k_{n=0}\binom{k}{n}2^{n-k}(\tfrac12+\epsilon\big)^n\Big) = \sum^\infty_{k=0}a_k\big(1+\epsilon\big)^k<\infty
  \end{align*}
It follows the radius if $f$ around $0$ is at least $1+\epsilon$ which is a contradiction.