# If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is analytic on $\{z:|z|<1\}\cup\{1\}$ and $a_n\ge 0$ then $R>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is analytic on $\{z:|z|<1\}\cup\{1\}$ and $a_n\ge 0$ then $R>1$.

I am not quite sure how to approach it. I thought it should be related to singular points but I can't see how. I would really benefit from any direction suggested.

Comment: There is a theorem (but I forget its name) which states that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ has convergence radius $R > 0$ and all $a_n$ are $\ge 0$, then $z = R$ is a *singular point* of the power series. That is essentially the topic of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482608/fz-sum-a-n-zn-a-n-geq0-with-radius-of-convergence-1-prove-that-1.

Comment: I shall check it out. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your assumption as: $f$ has a holomorphic continuation to a neighborhood of $z=1$.

Notice that $\sum a_n$ converges and $=f(1)$ because $f(x)\to f(1)$ as $x\to 1-$ through real values and $f(x)\ge \sum_{n\le N} a_nx^n\to\sum_{n\le N} a_n$. Similarly, by considering derivatives, we see that $\sum n(n-1)\ldots (n-k+1)a_n = f^{(k)}(1)$ for all $k\ge 0$.

By assumption, the series
$$
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k!} r^k = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{r^k}{k!}\sum_{n\ge k} n(n-1)\ldots (n-k+1) a_n = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} r^k = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n(1+r)^n
$$
converges for some $r>0$. Thus $R\ge 1+r$.