# If $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $1$ and all $a_n\geq 0$, then $z=1$ is a singular point of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Suppose $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ has convergence radius $1$. If all $a_n\geq 0$, then $z=1$ is a singular point of $f$.

The only proof I have seen can be found [here](https://sunlimingbit.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/pringsheim-theorem/). I have been trying to understand this for a while but I am still confused. There's an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482608/fz-sum-a-n-zn-a-n-geq0-with-radius-of-convergence-1-prove-that-1) as well but it's not clear to me either.

Queston: The proof mentions that the Taylor expansion about $z=\frac{1}{2}$ has an expression $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \big(z-\frac{1}{2}\big)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}c_n^ka_n\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n-k}$$ What are these $c_n^k$?

Comment: Maybe my interpretation of “singular point” doesn’t match yours. If $a_n = 1/n^2$, the power series has convergence radius $1$ but does not have a singularity at $1$.

Comment: @AlannRosas As per my definition, when $a_n=1/n^2$ the power series converges on the unit circle but you cannot extend it outside the closed unit ball, so it has singularity at every point on the unit circle.

Comment: @AlannRosas  I consider $z_0$ a singularity of $f$ if there is no open ball around $z_0$ where $f$ is analytic

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k^2}=\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$ which can be analytically continued outside the unit circle, but requires a branch cut, often taken along $(1,\infty)$. The fact that the power series does not converge outside $|z|\le1$ does not mean that the function cannot be continued outside that same circle.

Comment: @robjohn I checked the definition again and in a later chapter where analytic continuation is discussed a singular point is defined as follows: $z_0$ is a singularity of $f$ if there is no analytic $g$ such that $g=f$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$

Answer (score 1):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n
> =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\left(\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq k\leq n<\infty}a_n\binom{n}{k}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and observe $c^k_n$ is the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (2) we rearrange terms and write the double sum to conveniently see the region of indices.
- in (3) we change the order of sums.